# How to check internet connection after reboot android every 5min?

Tags: java, android

Hello I just start learn java, and need to check internet connection after reboot device. But after reboot has error
My code:
BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MainBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
           MainService.startService(context);
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
public class MainService extends Service {

public static void startService(Context context) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MainService.class));
    }

    Handler handler;
    Runnable test;
    public MainService() {
        handler = new Handler();
        test = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                qqq();
                handler.postDelayed(test, 300000); // 5min
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(test, 100);
    }

            public void qqq() {
                // Check for Internet Connection
                if (isConnected()) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

public boolean isConnected() {
        boolean connected = false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = nInfo != null && nInfo.isAvailable() && nInfo.isConnected();
            return connected;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Connectivity Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connected;
    }
```

But after reboot I have messege: "YourApp has stopped!"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to add following permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Hope this helps.